# Deleting items from a DropDownList in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdownbox

I have a DropDownList in my ASPX page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroups" runat="server" Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGroups_SelectionIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Also based on a condition I am populating the DropDownList in my code behind :

```
  List<Status> lstStatus  = new List<Status>();
  lstStatus = GetStatus() //Get's the list from db
  if (lstStatus != null && lstStatus.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlGroups.DataSource = lstStatus;
        ddlGroups.DataTextField = "StatusDescription";
        ddlGroups.DataValueField = "StatusID";
        ddlGroups.DataBind();
       /* ddlGroups.
        ddlGroups.Items.Remove("Completed");*/
    }
```

When I do this, I do not want the DropDownList to be poulated from the ASP.NET page markup. I.e. I want to remove the items added from the aspx code (only two of them).

Any help?

Comment: this is not asp-classic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear Dropdown and fill it as you want.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: that did it, i could have used it earlier but was confused that the AppendDataBoundItems = true would still append the items to the combo box . thanks anyways

Comment: AppendDataBoundItems should be flase then.

Answer (score 1):

```
            if (lstStatus != null && lstStatus.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlGroups.Items.Clear();
                ddlGroups.DataSource = lstStatus;
                ddlGroups.DataTextField = "StatusDescription";
                ddlGroups.DataValueField = "StatusID";
                ddlGroups.DataBind();
            }
```